# Form functions contain

Tags: forms

How I can send a form using functions php?

**Example**

```
function xxx1() { echo '<input type="text" name="xxx1" />'; }
function xxx2() { echo '<input type="text" name="xxx2" />'; }
```

**PHP code**

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    <?php
        xxx1();
        xxx2();
    ?>
</form>
```

It that possible?

Comment: yes, but not working

Comment: Where you put your code? In 1 file or 2 file?

Comment: in 2 file, it's problem?-

Comment: No, how you include the code in another code?

Answer (score 0):

Add php tags around the functions.
I tested your code in the following matter and everything is working correctly.

```
<?php
   function xxx1(){ echo '<input type="text" name="xxx1" />'; }
   function xxx2(){ echo '<input type="text" name="xxx2" />'; }
?>

<form method="POST" action="">
   <?php
       xxx1();
       xxx2();
   ?>
</form>
```